# null value in foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I copied the following paragraph from 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values; however, if any
>   column of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null values,
>   verification of all values that make up the FOREIGN KEY constraint is
>   skipped. To make sure that all values of a composite FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint are verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating
>   columns.

Could someone provide me with a simple example to help me understand the above? What verification the foreign key constraint will do? I think this has something to do with referential integrity.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more reason not to use composite PKS.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need an example if you think of it in another way.

If *any* of the fields in a composite foreign key are `NULL` then none of the other fields are checked for integrity until *all* fields of the key are provided.

Answer (score 2):

It is saying that if you have a composite foreign key using the two columns below, the relationship will not be enforced (because Name is `NULL` for OtherId 2).

```
OtherId  Name
-------  -------
1        Abe
2        NULL
3        Jim
4        Bob
```

Since the relationship is not enforced, you cannot enforce referential integrity.  If you specify that neither of the columns can have null values then you will never run into this situation and referential integrity will be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
create table t1 (id1 int, id2 int,
    constraint PK_T1 primary key (id1, id2))
create table t2 (id1 int, id2 int)

insert t2 values (1,null)

alter table t2 add constraint FK_T2_T1 foreign key (id1, id2) references t1(id1, id2)
```

The last line should cause an error.  After all, `t1` is empty, so the single row in `t2` can't possibly refer to anything.  But because one of the columns contains a `null` value, verification is skipped.